# How do you capitalize and hyphenate "at a glance" in a title?

Tags: hyphenation

I'd like to use the following as a section title:  Module At-a-Glance

Is it capitalized and punctuated properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look through [the Amazon listings](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Aat+a+glance&page=2&keywords=at+a+glance&ie=UTF8&qid=1408482709) shows

- "At-A-Glance" is a trademark for a line of calendars and other efficiency tools.
- All other uses omit the hyphens completely and capitalize neither *at* nor *a*.

Comment: How silly of me not to realize that my At-A-Glance calendar, which is right in front of me, is what made me think this needed to be hyphenated!

Answer (score 0):

You can either capitalize every word or leave out articles ('a') and prepositions ('at'), so forming:

> Module At A Glance

OR

> Module at a Glance

While "at a glance" is an accepted [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+a+glance), it's [not typically hyphenated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at-a-glance%2Cat%20a%20glance&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in usage.